# Why is Pakistan buying Chinese drones even though Chinese drones performed poorly in Libya?

Tags: pakistan

- [Why Chinese Drones Could Be A Nightmare For India Despite Best Of Radars and Fighter Jets?](https://eurasiantimes.com/chinese-drones-in-the-wrong-hands-could-spell-disaster-for-india-other-terror-prone-nations/)

In Libya, Chinese armed drones performed poorly against Turkish drones. So, to me, the purchase of Chinese drones makes absolutely no sense. The equation becomes bleaker when Turkey is a close ally of Pakistan. I mean, the Turkish option was absolutely open.

Why is Pakistan buying Chinese drones even though Chinese drones performed poorly in Libya?

Comment: can you clarify *Chinese armed drones performed poorly against Turkish drones* and link to some information supporting your claim?  far as I know, the vast majority of drones right now are surveillance or shoot-insurgents kinda drones.  if there are drones that target other drones, that would be news to me.  also, with drones as with most weapons, operator competence counts for a lot - I would expect Lybian irregulars to perform poorly against Turkish soldiers.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, https://lostarmour.info/libya/item.php?id=24255

Comment: several remarks - #1 your link shows only Lybian losses.  #2 It is surprisingly, surprisingly specific, suspiciously so:  armies do not typically divulge their losses in such details, it would help their enemies too much.  #3 nothing there gives me any comparisons to Turkish losses and #4 even assuming the info is correct, nothing tells what was pilot error vs actual malfunction or combat losses.  Ex: USAF was losing a fair bit of drones at landing by insisting on landing Predators manually vs the US Army letting it auto-land:  Predators have very, very, narrow tunnel vision, bad for landings

Answer (score 4):

- A particular drone or jet, or weapon in general may be good in a particular place and may not be good elsewhere. The technical details are usually not revealed.
- Since China is an old ally of Pakistan, and has regularly purchased weapons from them, it can be speculated that Pakistani forces are aware of Chinese technologies, which might or might not be applicable here. By this I mean, they might need lesser training time in comparison to weapons from other countries.
- Satellite communication, as mentioned below could be factor. It might be related with Chinese navigation system.
- Cost could be another factor. I will update details on it shortly.

Here is a news article regarding the procurement

> The CH-4 has a take-off mass between 1,200-1,300 kgs depending on the variant. It can also carry a wide range of payloads. **The UAV is now in service with military forces including the Iraqi Army and the Royal Jordanian Air Force.**
>
> Sources also stated that ALIT has offered Pakistan **command and control options, including direct line-of-sight and satellite communications.**
>
> https://www.timesnownews.com/amp/international/article/pakistan-buying-cai-hong-4-armed-drones-from-china/638224

Comment: [Indian media facing a crisis of credibility](https://www.dw.com/en/indian-media-facing-a-crisis-of-credibility/a-39120228)